# store a value in a variable

Tags: php, variables, date, insert

I have a date picker JS that outputs the date into the inputField, how do I go about putting that value into a variable as I want to insert it into my database, when I hit submit?

I would assume in my insert statement I would use, INSERT INTO xxxx (id, date) VALUES ($_POST['id'], **ANDTHENSOMETHINGHERE**)

```
    <input type="text" size="12" name="datefield"  id="inputField" />
  <?php $datefield = $_POST['datefield'];
  echo $datefield;
  ?>
```

Above is what I am thinking? but I know I am wrong

Comment: Use a hidden input field

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Im not actually using mysql, Im using postgresql, And I will be looking to add further security to combat against SQL injection once I have the basics of the system working

Comment: or maybe even drupals form API If I can get my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `<input>` a `name` attribute. It will then be submitted with the rest of the data. `id` is used for *client* side purposes (associating `<label>` elements, JS's `getElementByID`, CSSs `#` selector, etc).

Comment: Ok, I edited and I think that looks better, then I call the name via post in the SQL insert